# Display list of data on the basis of roles in MVC asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I have a list which shows all the videos uploaded by Admin and Users, But I want to apply some condition to individually display User and Admin uploads list (just want to separate list on the basis of roles). 
How can i do it?

This is the code which displays all the Videos

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var videos = db.Videos.Include(v => v.Artist).Include(v => v.Category);
        return View(videos.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Does the Videos table have a column for user roles?

Comment: No, In videos table there is only column of User Id, not for roles

Comment: Does you set role authentication in your application.

Comment: Can you share the "Video" class?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the video class

```
public class Video
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Length { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
        public string format { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public bool isblock { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> comments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Like> likes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HitCounter> Views { get; set; }   
 }
```